# Matlab doesn't display table completely

Tags: matlab

I have a table exchanged from a structure and I want to display it but when I write

```
T1 = struct2table(Structure(1))
disp(T1)
```

I get as display:

```
[1x13 double]    [1x13 double]    [1x13 double]
```

which I want to see completely. How can I do that?

PS: I want to display my structure as a table

Comment: `cell2mat(T1)`  ‍‍‍‍‍‍or probably `cell2mat(T1.')`  is what you want

Comment: what happens when you just do `T1 = struct2table(Structure(1))` and don't use `disp` or a semicolon to silence the output?

Comment: Add minimal code sample, so we can execute your code, and get the same result.  Example for minimal code: `S.A = {1:13, 1:13, 1:13};T = struct2table(S);disp(T);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using row-vectors instead of column-vector. Have you tryed with `T1 = struct2table(Structure(1)')`

Also, there's no need to use the command `disp`, it will show you the table automatically.